# How to set margins to a custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

Does anybody knows how can I set margins to a custom dialog? I'm asking because I've a custom dialog but when displayed it stretches to fill the parent, even though I set explicitly WRAP_CONTENT on the layout params.

Basically, the dialog contains a listview whose elements must be scrolled down, when the elements are 1 for example, it doesn't stretch, but when more items are added, then the dialog occupies the entire screen.

Any suggestions? I've trying all possible combinations of possible solutions without achieving satisfactory results

EDIT: Added the dialog layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="50dip"   
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <Button android:layout_height="32dip" android:layout_width="32dip" 
                android:id="@+id/guide_dialog_cross_button"
                android:background="@drawable/button_cross_white"/>

        </FrameLayout>


    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"/>

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Margins don't work for Dialogs, I imagine the top-level window view isn't a layout type that supports margins. I've seen posts saying margins will work when defined as the Dialog's style (rather than on the top-level view element), but this does not seem to work either.

What you need to do to work around the issue is to use an `inset` drawable for your Dialog background, and adjust any padding to account for the background's extra inset. In the example below, I'll just set left & right margins.

Dialog background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- drawable is a reference to your 'real' dialog background -->
<!-- insetRight and insetLeft add the margins -->
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/dialog_background" 
    android:insetRight="10dp"
    android:insetLeft="10dp">
</inset>
```

Dialog main view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- paddingTop / paddingBottom padding for the dialog -->
<!-- paddingLeft / paddingRight padding must add the additional inset space to be consistent -->
<!-- background references the inset background drawable -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_inset">

<!-- ...the rest of the layout... -->
```

You may also need to set the background colour of the Dialog itself to transparent. Add a colour resource like so:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

And set the window background colour of the dialog to this (note: you can't assign the colour directly, eclipse will complain)

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

This style should be passed to your Dialog's constructor as the `theme` argument, as in `new Dialog(context, R.style.Dialog);`

Comment: If you use the dialog_background_inset drawable as the windowBackground in the dialog style and don't use a background for the dialogs layout you don't have to worry about including extra padding in the layout to allow for the inset.

Comment: @ChrisJD I couldn't get it working. Anyway, pospi solution is working. Sometimes it really weird how much weird code Android needs to implement very simple things.

Comment: @pospi Do you know how to make it cancelable when clicked outside dialog's content? Because it's not working using your solution.

Comment: I would not think it's possible to do so - I'm just using a drawable to pad the edges so the viewport's hit zone is probably the full screen. I'm not even sure you can have two activities running with focus at the same time, but that may have changed since I last did any android dev (Gingerbread days)

Comment: why not use android.R.color.transparent instead if adding your own?

Comment: if that's a thing then for sure, no reason not to. Maybe it wasn't a part of Android at the time or maybe I just didn't know about it (:

Comment: Thanks.. Working fine.

Comment: what about if we use dimens in place of int value for margin?

Comment: Works, but positive button appears out of dialog, that looks weird

Comment: Guess this is better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991360/1621111

Comment: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Answer (score 68):

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting the window background on an InsetDrawable:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
...
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

ColorDrawable back = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
InsetDrawable inset = new InsetDrawable(back, 20);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(inset);

dialog.show();
```

In this case the dialog will appear with a margin of 20 to all edges.

Comment: It worked on newer APIs but when I tested on API 16 it showed a black border around the AlertDialog.

Comment: This also worked with `DialogFragment` and even with negative values (sic!): `new InsetDrawable(back, 16, -8, 16, -8);`. Great!

Answer (score 21):

Margin doesnt seem to work on the custom layout for the dialog, but padding works. Try setting the padding on the top level Linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" >
```

Answer (score 18):

As @simpleApps and @pospi pointed out, you need to add insets to the backgroundDrawable of the Dialog. If you are using a custom dialog, you can try with a drawable defined in a xml

```
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_dialog)
```

where R.drawable.background_dialog is defined as

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="20dp"
    android:insetTop="40dp"
    android:insetRight="20dp"
    android:insetBottom="40dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/color_background_fragment" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Answer (score 8):

A workaround can be done like this:

```
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().height = 
           (int) (getDeviceMetrics(context).heightPixels*0.8);
```

`**getDeviceMetrics** Method:

```
public static DisplayMetrics getDeviceMetrics(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me only by setting it after dialog.show();, like this: WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.height = (int) (Utils.getDeviceMetrics(LoginActivity.this).height * 0.8);
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

Comment: This is aswer is about dialog height instead of margins

Answer (score 8):

I was having trouble with the other solutions presented as the "OK" and "CANCEL" buttons went outside of the screen and it just looked weird. Instead, I used [android:windowMinWidthMinor & android:windowMinWidthMajor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302941/what-is-the-difference-between-windowminwidthmajor-and-androidwindowminwidthmaj) which looked better and incidentally also required less code. Nothing is needed in Java / Kotlin.

Here's all I did:

**1) Only use only one background drawable (I called mine dialog_box.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

**2) Set background in Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_box">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**3) Set style:**

```
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_box</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">85%</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: windowMinWidthMinor works, seems like default width alert Dialog

Comment: windowMinWidthMinor is really what I am looking for thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a straight-forward, programmatic way to set position and size of my dialog with margins.

I tested my approach for a `DialogFragment` by applying it in the `onCreateDialog` method:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    // create dialog in an arbitrary way
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog( savedInstanceState ); 
    DialogUtils.setMargins( dialog, 0, 150, 50, 75 );
    return dialog;
}
```

This is the method applying the margins to the dialog:

```
public static Dialog setMargins( Dialog dialog, int marginLeft, int marginTop, int marginRight, int marginBottom )
{
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if ( window == null )
    {
        // dialog window is not available, cannot apply margins
        return dialog;
    }
    Context context = dialog.getContext();

    // set dialog to fullscreen
    RelativeLayout root = new RelativeLayout( context );
    root.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );
    dialog.requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    dialog.setContentView( root );
    // set background to get rid of additional margins
    window.setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( Color.WHITE ) );

    // apply left and top margin directly
    window.setGravity( Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP );
    LayoutParams attributes = window.getAttributes();
    attributes.x = marginLeft;
    attributes.y = marginTop;
    window.setAttributes( attributes );

    // set right and bottom margin implicitly by calculating width and height of dialog
    Point displaySize = getDisplayDimensions( context );
    int width = displaySize.x - marginLeft - marginRight;
    int height = displaySize.y - marginTop - marginBottom;
    window.setLayout( width, height );

    return dialog;
}
```

Here are the helper methods I used:

```
@NonNull
public static Point getDisplayDimensions( Context context )
{
    WindowManager wm = ( WindowManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.WINDOW_SERVICE );
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics( metrics );
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    // find out if status bar has already been subtracted from screenHeight
    display.getRealMetrics( metrics );
    int physicalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight( context );
    int navigationBarHeight = getNavigationBarHeight( context );
    int heightDelta = physicalHeight - screenHeight;
    if ( heightDelta == 0 || heightDelta == navigationBarHeight )
    {
        screenHeight -= statusBarHeight;
    }

    return new Point( screenWidth, screenHeight );
}

public static int getStatusBarHeight( Context context )
{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier( "status_bar_height", "dimen", "android" );
    return ( resourceId > 0 ) ? resources.getDimensionPixelSize( resourceId ) : 0;
}

public static int getNavigationBarHeight( Context context )
{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier( "navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android" );
    return ( resourceId > 0 ) ? resources.getDimensionPixelSize( resourceId ) : 0;
}
```

The helper methods are explained in another of my [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418561/2011622).

This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/p-fischer/700fcdf5eff737ebf5ec4e64a0130e99) contains an extended versions that supports immersve mode too.

Answer (score 2):

if you extend Dialog Fragment, put this:

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog!!.getWindow()!!.setLayout(Constraints.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Constraints.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) // full width dialog
            val back = ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            val margin = 16
            val inset = InsetDrawable(back, margin)
            dialog!!.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(inset)
        }
    }
```

layoutparams is depend on your dialog parent view

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that worked for me was to wrap my entire View in another one, and set the margin to which is now the inner View.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="22dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ... Buttons, TextViews, etc

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Obs: that worked when I wanted margins **within** my AlertDialog. Not regarding the screen.

Comment: So you could've just added padding instead of wrapping it inside another layout.

Comment: Padding on the root view itself did not work. Please test the code before assuming it's wrong and downvoting it.

Comment: There is no need for another Layout,
`<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"'`

Answer (score 1):

you could make a new shape drawable resource and set color of it transparent :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

then you can add these simple lines in your dialog class onCreate method :

```
getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.drawble_resource_you_made_before);
```

**don't forget to put your dialog layout resource background white or any color you want** then you could easily by editing your dialog layout resource and customize it :)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Add the following styles

```
    <style name="CustomStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        </style>
```

Step 2. Extend custom dialog from `DialogFragment` and override the following

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.CustomStyle)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val dialog: Dialog? = dialog
        if (dialog != null) {
            val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            dialog.window?.setLayout(width, height)
            dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(InsetDrawable(ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.transparent, null)), 10, 10, 10, 10))
        }
    }
```

You will be able to get full screen dialog fragment with margins, without the status bar or overlapping navigation icons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier and cleaner solution than any of the existing answers:

```kotlin
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle(title)
    .create()

dialog.setView(view, spacingLeft, spacingTop, spacingRight, spacingBottom)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog#setView(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Note that `AlertDialog.Builder` does *not* have this method, but you have to call it on the dialog directly.

(Setting margins does not work because AlertController overrides LayoutParams when adding the view to the parent FrameLayout)

Comment: Nice and easy, I used with TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()

Answer (score 0):

1) change your main parent layout height `match_content` like below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_content"
    android:layout_margin="50dip"   
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center">
```

2) now add style to your styles.xml

```
<style name="dialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>
```

3) now add below code to show dialog :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DayActivity.this, R.style.dialogTheme);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom dialog with the background you can prefer the following code.
You can change window property `MATCH_PARENT` for full screen.

> My issue was width of dialog matching to its parent without margin

try following code as per requirement

```
    Window window = event_dialog.getWindow();
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    wlp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    wlp.flags &= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

set these property before `dialog.show()` **OR** you can set `LEFT,RIGHT,TOP,BOTTOM` margin to your dialog by setting `margin` to your `root` layout and `custom background` to its child layout like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/customLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/card_round_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to set the root layout to transparent background. Then, have its first child have margins or pre set height and width.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution for me

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(presenter.getActivity()).setView(view)
                .setBackgroundInsetStart((int) getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_20))
                .setBackgroundInsetEnd((int) getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_20)).create();
```

You can modify the margin start and end and dont use the `getWindow().setLayout()`  because this can lead to some issue

Answer (score 0):

**You can distance your `AlertDialog` from the parents by removing the `margin` from `width`.** *(Because the `AlertDialog` is placed in the middle and is separated from the parents by an equal amount.)*

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

  int device_with = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
  int margin = 40; // dp
  int width = (device_with - DPtoPX(margin));
  int height = ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
  dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

dialog.show();
```

This is `DPtoPX`(Dip to Pixel) converter method:

```
private int DPtoPX(int dp){
   return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density); 
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still looking for an elegant way to add margins, you can try this code:

```
 val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        .setView(R.layout.custom_layout)
        .create()
    dialog.window?.apply {
        decorView.setPadding(
            0,
            0,
            0,
            requireContext().resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_default)
        )
    }
    dialog.show()
```