# Prevent dialog from taking up whole width of screen in landscape mode - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog that contains long text. In portrait mode dialog looks good. But in landscape mode I don't want it to take up whole screen width. Is there any way to define max width of a dialog in % of screen's width? Because `wrap_content` won’t work in this case. Any solution?

Comment: You'll want to set a margin for the dialog. Check this older question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153489/how-to-set-margins-to-a-custom-dialog

Answer (score -3):

You should give `wrap_content` for both Height and Width of Parent Layout..will try.It should be Resolve your problem