# What is the difference between windowMinWidthMajor and android:windowMinWidthMajor

Tags: android

I want to set up a proper style for my ProgressDialog.
I like the default one but I want to customize it. I've tried to use AppCompat dialogs but they all setup some **weird width and height for my Dialog.**

I found that extending from MaterialDialog do the trick, so this code works:

```
<style name="ProgressDialogTheme" parent="MaterialBaseTheme.AlertDialog" >
</style>
```

This is because MeterialDialog itself setup custom width

```
<style name="MaterialBaseTheme.AlertDialog" parent="MaterialBaseTheme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    </style>
```

And I found that there is AppCompat dialog that set up the same custom width, here it is:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    </style>
```

**but it do not work**

The only difference is a **andorid namespace** at the beginning of MeterialDialog attribute.

Can someone explain why `android:windowMinWidthMajor`
do the trick?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.dimen.html#abc_dialog_min_width_major):

Min_witdh_major is:

> The platform's desired minimum size for a dialog's width when it is along the major axis (that is the screen is landscape). This may be either a fraction or a dimension.

And min_with_minor is:

> The platform's desired minimum size for a dialog's width when it is along the minor axis (that is the screen is portrait). This may be either a fraction or a dimension.

In appcompat, this value is set as 65%.

Answer (score 10):

[@Ian Wong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643915/2911458) is correct. Below are further details on that:

`android:windowMinWidthMajor` -> min_dialog_width in Landscape

`android:windowMinWidthMinor` -> min_dialog_width in Portrait

- The height of the dialog however isn't set and just wraps the content.

The actual values for `@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_major & @dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_minor` is defined in the following path:

[image: location of actual values defined for the dimensions]

`@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_major` - is `65%` to `45%` depending on the screen size.
`@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_minor` - is `95%` to `72%` depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

See also the [original docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#windowMinWidthMajor) that introduced the values in Api 11:

`windowMinWidthMajor`

> The minimum width the window is allowed to be, along the major axis of
> the screen. That is, when in landscape. Can be either an absolute
> dimension or a fraction of the screen size in that dimension.
>
> May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
> with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
> (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
> font size), in (inches), and mm (millimeters).
>
> May be a fractional value, which is a floating point number appended
> with either % or %p, such as "14.5%". The % suffix always means a
> percentage of the base size; the optional %p suffix provides a size
> relative to some parent container.
>
> Constant Value: 16843606 (0x01010356)

And similarly for `windowMinWidthMinor` ("That is, when in portrait.").