# How to add margins to Left and Right to Custom AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have created a Custom AlertDialog like this -

```
remark_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the
        // dialog layout
        remark_builder.setCancelable(true);
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_remark_dialog, null);
        remark_builder.setView(dialogView);

if (remark_dialog == null || !remark_dialog.isShowing()) {

            remark_dialog = remark_builder.create();
            remark_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            remark_dialog.show();

        }
```

I want to add margins to the left and right of this alertdialog.

I have tried a lot of code over the internet but it is emphasizing on setting the width and height of the Alert Dialog. 
I don't want to set the width and height. I want to add margins to the left and right of the AlertDialog which is MATCH_PARENT.

My current alert dialog looks like :

[image]

I want to add margins like 40 or 50 or according to the device density. is this possible?

Comment: You want to make it smaller?

Comment: Take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7655350/4385913

Comment: Yeah, width. Are your sure the provided link will work??

Comment: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown> getting error.

Comment: please provide xml layout of dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below method to achieve this.

```
     Rect displayRectangle = new Rect();
            Window window = mContext.getWindow();

            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayRectangle);
remark_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        malertdialog.show();
        malertdialog.getWindow().setLayout((int)(displayRectangle.width() *
                0.8f), (int)(displayRectangle.height() / 2));
```

adjust the decimal value for the width and height as per what ratio you need.

Comment: Your code is working but there is one problem. The dialog is not in the center. I tried setting the gravity using this - remark_dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); but it is not working. Any suggestions??

Comment: my remark dialog layout is wrap_content. How to set the dialog to the center gravity?