# How to set dialog outer margins? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, margins

I need add custom margins around dialog. Any suggestion how to do this?
(dialog position top : 100 px, left 50 px, etc)

Comment: by setting `layout_margin` I suppose, no?

Comment: don't use px use dp instead ....

Comment: are you using custom dialog or simple by default one

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Try this

```
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setTop(100);
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setLeft(100);
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a old question, but if anyone still needs a help...

You can use a `inset`to set margins to a `Custom dialog`.

Create a `dialog_inset.xml` in your drawable folder:

```
<inset
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/dialog_background"
android:insetRight="15dp"
android:insetBottom="15dp"
android:insetLeft="15dp">
</inset>
```

Look, the `android:drawable`attribute is calling my dialog custom background. In my case, is a white window rounded.

This is my `dialog_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <stroke android:color="#4c252525" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And now you need to put this `android:background="@drawable/dialog_isset"` at your **`parent view`** of your **custom dialog layout**.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you mate.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.cutomDialog);
...
...
Dialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
params.x = locationByX;
params.y = locationByY;
params.width = dialogWidth;
params.height = dialogHeight;

dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```